# DataTable is not displaying data received by AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently learning how to display AJAX-received data to DataTables using .NETCore 6 Razor Pages. Here's the front-end code:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th hidden>Id</th> //I want the id column to be hidden; all SQL tables have the same 4 columns
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Daily Range Minimum</th>
            <th>Daily Range Maximum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.Client)
        {
            <tr>
                <td hidden>@row.Id</td>
                <td>@row.Region</td>
                <td>@row.range1</td>
                <td>@row.range2</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

    var dataTable, headers;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

        $('.button-container button').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
            fetchDataForButton(buttonId);
        });
    });

        // Function to handle data retrieval based on the button id
    function fetchDataForButton(buttonId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            url: '/wagetable?handler=CollectData',
            dataSrc: '',
            data: { buttonId: buttonId },

            success: function (response) {
                
                console.log("Success callback reached");
                console.log("Data received:", response);

                //Destroy previous DataTable if exists
                if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataTable')) {
                    $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
                }

                // Clear the existing headers
                $('#dataTable thead').empty();

                // Add the new headers
                var headers = getHeadersForButton(buttonId);
                var headerRow = $('<tr>');
                headers.forEach(function (header) {
                    headerRow.append($('<th>').text(header));
                });

                $('#dataTable thead').append(headerRow);

                // Add the new data to the DataTable
                dataTable.clear().rows.add(response).draw();

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
                // Handle error as needed
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to get headers based on the buttonId
    function getHeadersForButton(buttonId) {
        // Implement logic to retrieve headers based on the buttonId
        // Example:
        switch (buttonId) {
            case 'btnSSS':
                return ['Monthly Range Minimum', 'Monthly Range Maximum', 'Monthly Credit'];
            case 'btnIndustry':
                return ['Industry', 'Monthly Range Minimum', 'Monthly Range Maximum'];
            case 'btnRegion':
                return ['Region', 'Range1', 'Range2'];
            // Add cases for other buttonIds
            default:
                return [];
        }
    }


</script>
```

When a button is clicked, AJAX sends the button id to a function in the Model page that handles data retrieval. Here's the back-end code:

```
public IActionResult OnPostCollectData(string buttonId)
{
    IEnumerable<object> data = null;

    // Call the appropriate SQL function based on the buttonId
    switch (buttonId)
    {
        case "btnSSS":
            data = employeeRepository.GetAllRanges(); // All are SQL functions that retrieve data from SQL tables
            break;
        case "btnIndustry":
            data = employeeRepository.GetAllIndustries();
            break;
        case "btnRegion":
            data = employeeRepository.GetAllRegions();
            break;
        // Add cases for other buttonIds
        default:
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OnPostCollectData called for buttonId: {buttonId}");
        return new JsonResult(new { Data = data });
    
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the OnPostGetData request.");
        return BadRequest(new { ErrorMessage = "An error occurred. Please check the logs for more details." });
    }
}
```

**Problem and Solutions tried**

The problem is that the data is not displaying; table headers are successfully displayed but not the table cell values. I've noticed that:

- there are no Javascript errors in console
- the 'response' variable is not null or empty; in the console log, the data received is being displayed correctly as an array of table row values
- calling `dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();` again after `dataTable.clear().rows.add(response).draw();` causes Incorrect column count error. I assume that's because it's redundant?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the  browser log? Are you getting any error there?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron No errors, not even under Network tab. I'm using Google Chrome as browser if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your API will return the response which is a single object containing the `data` array. For example:

[`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) requires an array to insert multiple rows into the DataTable.

```js
dataTable.clear().rows.add(response.data).draw();
```

2. As you have destroyed the DataTable, you need to create/re-initialize the `DataTable` instance before adding the response data into the table rows. Also, you should provide the columns for the projection with the keys/fields in the response as below:

```js
dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable(  
  {
    columns: [
        { data: 'range1' },
        { data: 'range2' },
        { data: 'monthly_Credit' }
    ]
  }
);
```

3. Would also recommend emptying the `<tbody>` element as this may result in an issue when instantiating the `DataTable` and adding the rows.

Complete code:

```js
//Destroy previous DataTable if exists
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataTable')) {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
}

// Clear the existing headers
$('#dataTable thead').empty();
  
// Clear tbody
$('#dataTable tbody').empty();
  
// Add the new headers
var headers = getHeadersForButton(buttonId);
var headerRow = $('<tr>');
headers.forEach(function(header) {
  headerRow.append($('<th>').text(header));
});

$('#dataTable thead').append(headerRow);

dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable(  
  {
    columns: getColumns(buttonId).map((x) => ({ data: x }))
  }  
);
  
// Add the new data to the DataTable
dataTable.clear().rows.add(response.data).draw();

function getColumns(buttonId) {
  // Implement logic to retrieve column based on the buttonId
  // Example:
  switch (buttonId) {
    case 'btnSSS':
      return ['range1', 'range2', 'monthly_Credit'];
    case 'btnIndustry':
      return [
        /* Add properties for projection */
      ];
    case 'btnRegion':
      return [
        /* Add properties for projection */
      ];
    // Add cases for other buttonIds
    default:
      return [];
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qwzz22?file=index.html)

Comment: `response.Data` results in an error: `jquery.dataTables.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`. I tried using `Object.keys(response.Data)` but it results in undefined value.

Comment: Can you share the API response? I suspect that possibly the field name was applied as camel case. `response.data`. Would be great to share it for clarification.

Comment: `Data inside received: undefined
jquery.dataTables.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at B.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:4:59562)
    at B.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:4:52237)
    at B.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:4:59510)
    at Function.add (jquery.dataTables.min.js:4:53720)
    at Object.success (wagetable/:250:44)
    at fire (jquery-3.7.0.js:3213:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.7.0.js:3343:7)
    at done (jquery-3.7.0.js:9617:14)`

Comment: `at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.7.0.js:9878:9)`

This is the affected code in the j.s. :

`e("rows.add()", function(o) {
        var t = this.iterator("table", function(t) {
            **for (var e, n = [], a = 0, r = o.length; a < r; a++)**
                (e = o[a]).nodeName && "TR" === e.nodeName.toUpperCase() ? n.push(ut(t, e)[0]) : n.push(x(t, e));
            return n
        },`

@Yong Shun

Comment: **Please share the API response**. You are showing the error without providing the input, it is difficult to debug and find the root cause. As what I have seen, `Data` is undefined.

Comment: I apologize, this is my first time doing this code. The value of Response under Network tab under Google Chrome is as follows:

`{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "range1": "0.00",
            "range2": "4,249.99",
            "monthly_Credit": "4,000.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "range1": "4,250.00",
            "range2": "4,749.99",
            "monthly_Credit": "4,500.00"
        },` ....

Comment: ....... `{
            "id": 51,
            "range1": "29,250.00",
            "range2": "29,749.99",
            "monthly_Credit": "20,000.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 52,
            "range1": "29,750.00",
            "range2": "1,000,000",
            "monthly_Credit": "20,000.00"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Under Payload, the data sent is as follows:

Query String Parameters
handler: CollectData

Form Data
buttonId: btnSSS

@Yong Shun

Comment: Hi, I had update the answer with the demo link. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: At first, your code didn't work. However, I noticed that your `response.data` is a lowercase 'd' while mine was uppercase. I changed mine to lowercase and it worked! Thanks for the help. =D